# Use the same icon when starting from commandline vs starting from terminal

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, .desktop

I have an eclipse installation that was not installed through the repositories. To be able to launch it conveniently,

- I symlinked the path to eclipse to `/usr/bin`, (so that it can be started by running the command `eclipse` from a terminal)
- I created a `.desktop` file, to start it from the dash.
- After starting from the dash, I locked the icon that appeared to the Launcher.

This all works, the icon specified in the `.desktop` file shows (after some trial and error) and everything.

However, when I run `eclipse` from terminal, it does not use the item that I locked to the Launcher, but creates a new one. When I start Eclipse through the dash, it *does* use the item locked to the Launcher. Furthermore, when running `eclipse` from the terminal, it apparently does not know which icon to use, since it shows a grey sheet with a question mark instead.

I would like Ubuntu to recognize that I'm executing the same command in both cases, and have it treat them identically. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was that there were multiple `.desktop` files for the same Eclipse executable. Deleting all but one of them solved the issue.

If you launch Eclipse before creating a `.desktop` file, then right-click that Eclipse in the launcher and click *Lock to launcher*, Ubuntu goes about this by automatically creating a `.desktop` file for you, behind the scenes.

If you unlock it from the launcher later on, the auto-generated `.desktop` file is *not* removed. Of course, if you then manually create a `.desktop` file, there are two `.desktop` files, and this may result in the behaviour described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on Unity, as I don't have an install to test with. However this works on Gnome on 14.10.

```
gtk-launch eclipe
```

assuming your desktop file is eclipse.desktop. If not just change eclipse to whatever you named the desktop file without the .desktop extension

Comment: Surprisingly, the result depends on whether eclipse is already open. If I first start eclipse from the dash or the launcher and then start a second instance using `gtk-launch eclipse`, it is grouped under the same (pretty) icon in the launcher.

However, if I run `eclipse` first (resulting in the ugly questionmark icon),  and then run `gtk-launch eclipse`, it is grouped under _that_ icon.

If I run it on its own, without having another instance of eclipse, it gives the questionmark icon, so that's visually the same as running `eclipse`.